# Why my result of the operation is rounded down to 0?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've function in T-SQL:

```
sum(ar.tothandlingtime)/(60*60*24)
```

and in my result set I've all 0, because the result of this part of the day. Always is below 0.
I want to continue to work on the results, so I need an accurate result in a form and in a view. How?

Comment: Compare the results of `select 10 / 3, 10 / 3.0`

Comment: You are dividing by an `int` trying converting that to a `decimal` to get the remainder.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), and thus truncating the decimal.

To get your desired result, try converting one side to a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx):

```
CONVERT(decimal(19, 18), SUM(ar.tothandlingtime))/(60*60*24)
```

Using this lets SQL know to perform decimal-based division.

If you need to, you can also play with the precision and scale of the decimal (read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Of course, if you don't care about the precision, you can also achieve this by putting `.0` after each hard-coded number:

```
(60.0*60.0*24.0)
```

For example,

```
select 5/(60.0*60.0*24.0) -- Result: 0.000057870370 
select 5/(60*60*24) -- Result: 0
```

In my experience, this is generally the quickest way to get it to register as decimal division without explicitly using a `CAST` or `CONVERT`. If you were strictly using integer-based column values or aggregate functions, though, you would need to convert it, like in the first example.

Comment: I used the first method and I've few result f.e. `0E-16`... Can I get the exact result?

Comment: Try make the decimal more precise declare it as (19,18).

Comment: @CiucaS, yeah, `(19, 5)` was just an arbitrary precision/scale

Comment: @user3815737, I've updated the precision in my answer based on CiucaS's suggestion

Comment: If you want to test the precision of a divide operation, I always use this example 

    declare nr1 decimal(20,19),
      nr2 decimal(20,19)
    set nr1 = EXP(1.0)
    set nr2 = PI();
    print nr1/@nr2

As EXP and PI are "infinit" numbers.  Don't forget the "@" in front of the variables. I can't add more then one in a com.

Answer (score 0):

You are dividing by an int trying converting that to a decimal. Change it like this

```
sum(ar.tothandlingtime)/CAST((60*60*24) AS DECIMAL ))
```